# Virtual hosts WAMP 2.1

Tags: apache, http, wamp, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a virtual host for a project that I need to do. 
As many tutorials define I activated the virtual host file

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Placed a virtual host in te file

```
<VirtualHost *80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Jeroen\Work\Ba\CMS\trunk"
    ServerName local.ba-check.be
</VirtualHost>
```

The hosts file also got a line extr

```
127.0.0.1 local.ba-check.be
```

My localhost works, but it returns my document root. Also the error log always gives me this error.

```
[Thu Jul 07 14:22:55 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/httpd-2.2-x64, referer: http://local.ba-check.be/
```

I hope somebody could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems solved

After some time I just reinstalled WAMP and then it worked great.